# Порядок слов при сочетании имени числительного и притяжательного местоимения

Tags: числительные, местоимения, местоимение, порядок-слов

**Если бы он учёл (12 моих простых советов / мои 12 простых советов) о том, как...**

**Если бы он учёл (мои несколько / несколько моих) простых советов о том, как...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Начнем с реальных примеров:**

(1) Нам предстояло выступать на маленькой сцене, поэтому **мои несколько составов** разъезжались по разным углам площадки. [Татьяна Тарасова, Виталий Мелик-Карамов. Красавица и чудовище (1984-2001)]

мои несколько составов  - все мои составы (их было несколько),

несколько моих составов - про все составы не сказано.

(2) Затем ― **мои несколько жалоб в ЦК**, и все оставлены без ответа. [А. И. Солженицын. Бодался теленок с дубом (1967-1974)]

мои несколько жалоб  ― все мои жалобы,

несколько моих жалоб ― про все жалобы не сказано.

Аналогично с цифрами.

**2) Заданные примеры:**

**мои 12 простых советов**  ― советы сведены в группу и, возможно, опубликованы под таким названием,

н**есколько моих простых советов**  ― речь идет об устных советах, их количество неопределенное (это обычная ситуация).

Answer (score 2):

Все эти варианты допустимы, но воспринимаются по-разному.

1. a) **... несколько моих простых советов о том...** — звучит нейтрально и подходит к любой ситуации;
   б) **... мои несколько простых советов о том..**. — в этом есть напряжённость, связанная с тем, что "мои несколько" воспринимается как компактная группа советов, на которую ссылаются целиком, будто они даны единовременно (где-то записаны или даже напечатаны) — если такая ситуация имеет место, то выбор этого варианта обоснован.
2. **12 моих простых советов / мои 12 простых советов**

Отличие от первого случая состоит в *определённости* количества советов, и это само по себе указывает на ситуацию, в которой советы подсчитаны. Предпочесть же стоит **второй вариант**, явно указывающий на "группу (записанных) советов",  в первом же случае вне контекста предложение можно понять и иначе: будто человек в течение какого-то времени давал простые советы, а потом подсчитал, сколько же раз он это сделал, помня, что не повторялся; либо что из общего количества данных советов "он" не учёл ровно 12, что тоже странно.

Comment: Если бы я мог дать два балла за этот ответ— непременно дал бы!